# getting failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]

Tags: adb, logcat

I am trying to remove com.oppo.market from my realme 5 using adb but it is again and again giving me error saying `FAILURE [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]` . 
I tried both pm uninstall com.oppo.market and pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.oppo.market but no success ,whereas I managed to remove browser and other types of bloatware using adb . Why is it giving me the this error  for trying to delete app market ? What can be the solution ?

This is the logcat :- https://easyupload.io/bh6ssq

Comment: could you please attach logcat?

Comment: how to insert logcat ? It is too long

Comment: just attach the logcat that comes after invoking the adb command